# IATS ACH Civi is not recording when a donation has been refunded or returned

Tags: civicontribute, iats, refund

Civi is not recording when a donation has been refunded or returned. Is there a way for Civi to record returns or would these have to be recorded manually?
IATS EXTENSION:  1.7.4

Answer (score 1):

That’s correct and by design. Refunding for example a donation may have other business consequences like revoking a charitable tax receipt already issued for the original donation so best to have a finance/admin have eyes and hands on refunds and ensure the entire refund procedure for their specific org is followed.